# Doing multiple SQL queries in one query (aka saving doing two network round trips)

Tags: sql

Assume your connection from your web server to your DBA server is extremely slow, and you need to do a series of three queries to handle a single web request. Is there a way to combine the queries into one? Assume the following scenario

```
person.id person.name
1         James
2         Stacy
```

.

```
country.id country.name
1          USA
2          UK
```

.

```
location.person_id location.country_id
1                  1
1                  2
```

The web form would post two variables, ie name="James" country="China" and you want to do the following

- Does "James" exist, if not, insert james
- Does "China" exist, if not, insert china
- Does "James" live in "China", if not insert relationship

ie something like

```
select person.id, country.id, location.person_id
from person, country, location
where
    person.name="James" and
    country.name="China" and
    person.id=location.id and country.id=location.country_id
```

The above query is not useful because it will return no records if either the person, or the country or the location does not exist.

I know that it would be possible to do this using a stored procedure but not all databases support stored procedures.

Comment: I recognise this is quite a strange question and it would be better if you can just fix the network latency issues. But it would be neat to know if it were possible.

Comment: why dont you create procedure and divide the task or you want do in sql statement?

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to query the contents of all three tables using one SQL statement. I agree, that if your database supports stored procedures it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: You cannot insert into more than 1 table with one statement. But you can with a stored procedure or if multiple statements are allowed in one query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is very simple

```
SELECT (SELECT person.id from person WHERE person.name = 'James') as Name,
       (SELECT country.id from country WHERE country.name="China") as Country,
       (SELECT location.person_id from location WHERE person.id = location.id and country.id = location.country_id and person.name = 'James' and country.name="China") as Location
```

Comment: The 3rd subquery needs adjustment.

Comment: I tested this out on mysql and it doesn't seem to quite work, The name and country subqueries work. The final subquery appears to return arbitrary location records unrelated to the person.id and country.id from the first two subqueries.

Comment: The two highest ranked answers provide workable answers (ie use union, or use subqueries as part of the select statement). They are both "correct" answers so its hard to rank a correct answer. I will mark this one as correct on the basis that it is simpler

Comment: I have edited the query i hope this will work fine. Although the coditions in the last sub query can be reduced i think.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this (use a `UNION`):

```
SELECT 
    id  as id,
    'PERSON' as type
FROM person
WHERE name = 'James'
UNION
SELECT 
    id as id,
    'COUNTRY' as type
FROM country
WHERE name = 'China'
UNION
SELECT 
    person_id as id,
    'LOCATION' as type
FROM location
JOIN person ON person.id = location.person_id
JOIN country ON country.id = location.country_id
WHERE person.name = 'James'
AND   country.name = 'China'
```

This will give you all rows that match the respective names, together with their types. Looking at raheel shan's answer I think that would be even quicker, consider this one as a feasible alternative :-)

Comment: @AmritpalSingh I see no such requirement. If you use this solution you get rows. If you want one column for each entity type then use raheel shan's answer as I already suggested above.

Comment: When result will be obtained he need to check whether that is person or location. rather should be a single call column doing the job

Comment: This is technically a correct answer, it is what I initially thought of as well. The other higher ranked answer seems simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSSQL (which is hard to see from your question) it supports Multiple recordsets. You enable it via connection string, execute multiple selects from stored procedure, and access it via dataset as multiple datatables ...

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for  you to get the whole data in one dataset  then you should use full join

```
select person.*, country.*, location.*
from person
full join location
on person.id=location.id
full join country
on country.id=location.country_id
where isnull(person.name,'James')='James' and
isnull(country.name,'China')='China'
```

Comment: it does not seems to provide required result

Comment: fixed a little. not it looks ok

Comment: joining is a possiblity but I recommend to use aliases for all columns you want to return (e.g. `person.id as person_id`) instead of `.*` as the column names of the different tables are overlapping.